# How does this Javascript code snippet print 'false'?

Tags: javascript

Looking at the code below, I don't understand how (typeof a !== 'undefined') works. I understand that variable "a" is not inside the IIFE, so it is undefined outside of it. But I don't understand how the code prints out 'false'

```
(function(){
   var a = 3;   
})();

console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined'));
//prints false- but how and why?
```

If I remove the typeof and just execute

```
console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined')); 
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

I get an error saying Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined. So how is it that it runs fine when typeof is present- and it errors when typeof is removed? That's my confusion

Comment: `a` is only defined inside the context of `function()` .  Hence why `a` is `undefined`.  Also, `function()` is never run.

Comment: @KraangPrime You should post that as the answer. Also, take a look at this resourse to learn more about [JavaScript Scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: typeof returns type as a string (e.g. "string", "number", "undefined"). Then it displays false since a !== 'undefined' is a conditional expression which will be either true or false.

Comment: @KraangPrime If you look closer, you will see that was not the question and the function does indeed run.

Comment: I don't understand where the confusion is. You already know that `a` is undefined (*"variable "a" is not inside the IIFE, so it is undefined outside of it"*) so why is it a surprise that the type of `a` is undefined?

Comment: @BDawg -  re-read the solution. I cover scope as well as break down the condition being evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the post has the presence or absence of "typeof" interchanged - it should be inserted in the first example and removed in the second. But anyway.

> So how is it that it runs fine when typeof is present- and it errors when typeof is removed?

The answer is in the nature and design of the `typeof` operator.

Whether in strict mode or not, reading the value of an undeclared variable to get its value generates a "Reference Error: a is not defined" *except when using the `typeof` operator*.

The `typeof` operator was designed to allow testing for an undeclared variable and returns the primitive value `undefined` if it has not been declared. There really is no other means of performing this test without thowing an error.

The test result is still ambiguous if the reason for the test is not clearly understood: the type of a declared variable with value `undefined` also returns "undefined".

So in the first(?) example if you test `typeof a !== 'undefined`, `a` is undefined/undeclared outside the IIFE, `typeof a` returns "undefined" which compared to itself in an inequality test returns false.

When tested without 'typeof` you get the reference error.

Comment: Thank you, yes you're correct- I interchanged them by mistake. I fixed it. Your last paragraph made the solution clear. I was first evaluating a !== 'undefined' and then trying to do the typeof operator on that; that's why it wasn't making any sense to me. However, you pointed out that typeof a is executed first and that is then compared to 'undefined'. Yes, now I see my mistake. I was not reading the evaluation correctly.

Answer (score 4):

As you say, `a` doesn't exist outside the IFFE. It is therefore undefined in the different scope.

```
//Enter the following in your console.
typeof a   // --> "undefined"

(function(){
   var a = 3;   
})();

typeof a   // --> "undefined" (Still)
```

The issue may come when you're checking the type, and perhaps misunderstanding the Boolean evaluation (it's kind of a double negative). `typeof a === 'undefined'` is `true`, therefore, `typeof a !== 'undefined'` is `false`.

Comment: `a` is undefined and attempting to use it raises a `ReferenceError` because it doesn't exist in that scope. `typeof` seems to work with things that don't exist. (And if you have a second question, it may be better to open a second question rather than editing the original.)

Comment: Sorry, I guess my original question was not the thing I really wanted to know. That's very bizarre behaviour for the typeof. Is there any official  documentation on this behaviour of typeof